# Find coefficient in series expansion of $x^2C^3(x)$

Tags: combinatorics, functional-equations, catalan-numbers, lagrange-inversion

I need to find the $n$-th coefficient of the expression $P(x)=x^2C^3(x)$ where $C(x)$ is the generating function for the Catalan numbers: $$C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$

I'm trying to solve the problem via [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), using this fact, $$[x^n]P(x)=[x^{n-2}]C^3(x),$$ and $C(x)$ satisfies the functional equation $$C(x)=1+xC^2(x),$$

do you know how to use this equation for the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xC^2(x)=C(x)-1$ gives
$$P(x)=xC(x)(C(x)-1)=xC^2(x)-xC(x)=C(x)-1-xC(x),$$
hence $P_0=0$ and
$$\forall n\ge1\quad P_n=C_n-C_{n-1}.$$